# Posting a GraphQL mutation with Spring Boot WebClient

Tags: java, spring, graphql

There are tons of guides out there on how to create GraphQL APIs in Java, but close to zero on how to consume them, so I come here. I'm using Spring Boot WebClient to consume an external GraphQL API and I'm having some trouble with posting mutations. I have a factory class that produces my consumer here:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConsumerProducer {

    String url = "{GRAPHQL_API_URL}";

    @Bean
    public MyConsumer myConsumer(WebClient.Builder webclientBuilder) {
        return new MyConsumer(
                webclientBuilder
                        .baseUrl(url)
                        .defaultHeaders(this::defaultHeaders)
                        .build()
        );
    }

    private void defaultHeaders(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {
        httpHeaders.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpHeaders.setBearerAuth("{API_KEY}");
    }
```

And then I have the consumer itself:

```
public class MyConsumer {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    private static final String MUTATION = "mutation { CreateArea(id: \"3\", itemType: \"Area\", name: \"NewArea\") { id name }}";

    public MyConsumer(WebClient webClient) {
        this.webClient = webClient;
    }

    public CreateAreaResponse createArea() {
        var request = new GraphQLRequest(MUTATION, null);

        var res = webClient.post()
                .bodyValue(request)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(CreateAreaResponse.class)
                .block();

        return res;
    }
}
```

The GraphQLRequest class looks like this:

```
@Value
public class GraphQLRequest {
    String mutation;
    Object variables;
}
```

I then call the `createItem()` method from somewhere else in my code. This approach works fine with queries, so if I just simply switch my `MUTATION` with some `QUERY` for instance `"query { Item { id }}";` then it returns the response just fine. However with my mutation I get a `400 Bad Request` from the API with no more descriptive error messages. Does anyone immediately see anything wrong with my mutation string or the way it's posted to the API?

EDIT:
I tried comparing mutations in GraphiQL and Postman and found something weird. The mutation works fine in GraphiQL, but if I copy/paste the mutation into Postman it does not work. Below are screenshots of the request and response first in GraphiQL, then in Postman with errors.

[image]

[image]

Error message in Postman:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Unknown argument \"id\" on field \"Mutation.CreateArea\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 4,
                    "column": 14
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"
            }
        },
        {
            "message": "Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"Mutation.CreateArea\".",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 4,
                    "column": 21
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"
            }
        },
        {
            "message": "Field \"CreateArea\" argument \"data\" of type \"_AreaCreate!\" is required, but it was not provided.",
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 4,
                    "column": 3
                }
            ],
            "extensions": {
                "code": "GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Just a guess, but is it possible, that you're missing a comma??

I mean: Does `mutation { CreateArea(id: \"3\", itemType: \"Area\", name: \"NewArea\") { id, name }}` works? a comma between id and name?

Comment: No, that does nothing I'm afraid

Comment: I recommend you generating request classes based on your schema so that your client code is always aligned with the server schema. Here's the plugin which can do that: https://github.com/kobylynskyi/graphql-java-codegen

Comment: do you find the solution